# How to change year date in CSSearchableItem (content type — kUTTypeMovie)?

Tags: ios, search, movie, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I have an app with video content and I track all viewed items with `NSUserActivity` to add it to Spotlight. The result looks perfect, except year date, it is always a year when `NSUserActivity` was added to the index. But I need to change this to release year of a movie.

[image: Movie item representation in Spotlight]

```
let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.bundleid.movie")
activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
activity.title = "Mess"
let movie = kUTTypeMovie as String
let attributes = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: movie)
attributes.title = "Mess"
attributes.contentDescription = "Even if you get behind bars..."
attributes.thumbnailData = try? Data(contentsOf: thumbURL) // cover
attributes.rating = NSNumber(value: 3.7)
attributes.ratingDescription = "(Kinopoisk: 7.9, IMDb: 7.4)"
attributes.duration = NSNumber(value: 5785) // 1:36:25 in sec
attributes.contentCreationDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "1989") // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
activity.contentAttributeSet = attributes
```

I'm trying setting not only `attributes.contentCreationDate` but also `addedDate` and all other Dates available in `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Media.h`. But it is always `2018`(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this.

However, when I put this `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` not inside of a `NSUserActivity` but instead inside a `CSSearchableItem` and index that with `CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems()`, the search result says `1989` as desired.

Would that work for you?